# merge multiple solr facceted search into one

Tags: php, lucene, solr, facet, faceted-search

i have an array of products. For each product I have to crate an solr faceted search.

Example for the following "products":

```
Computer
TV
MP3-Player
```

by using faceted search I like to determine, how often every product exists in field PRODUCT.
With the following result

```
Comupter (3)
  -apple
  -ibm
  -dell
TV (5)
  -sony
  -toshiba
  [...]
MP3-player (10)
  -[...]
```

Right now, i realize that by using one faceted search for every word/product. 
That works, but the results returned in 400ms by using the following options:

```
'facet' => 'true'
'facet.field' => 'PRODUCT'
'facet.method' => 'enum'
 'facet.limit'=>200
'facet.mincount'=>4
 'fq' => 'PRODUCT:computer'    <- by iterating an array with PHP i change the product (computer,tv,...) on every iteration
```

Unfortunately in real life there are not 3 product (like the example above), there are round about 100 products, which are relevant. That means: the PHP script hast to request 100 solr searches, with 400ms - so the script runs 40 seconds, which is to long.
I'm unable to run an unlimited/unrestricted faceted search for "all" products (without "fq="), because there are thousend of products and I dont need the information only fro a every.

Is there a way to realize a better performance for example be merge those multiple solr requests into one?

Thank you!

Comment: i doubt you will get results for `"TV"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite get that, but can't you just create one filter query for the products that are relevant to the query:

```
facet' => 'true'
'facet.field' => 'PRODUCT'
'facet.method' => 'enum'
'facet.limit'=>200
'facet.mincount'=>4
'fq' => 'PRODUCT:(computer OR tv OR mp3-player)'
```

And then do some processing on the returned results?

Comment: sorry, my question was not explicit enough. So i updated the example above. As you can see, i'm interested in the frequency and also the manufacturer of an product. By running your example i get all the manufacturer at onces without the information which belongs to a specific product.

Comment: do you control the schema? can you add fields? A way would be to store concatenated information, such as Computer/Ibm etc (which would strictly speaking be a taxonomy), and then decode that in the client

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't want to filter on a specific type value when faceting. The idea behind faceting is that it will do a "group" and "count" for all values in the faceted field (for all items that matches the original query).

If you simply remove your fq-parameter you will see that in return you will get a list of all values in PRODUCT-field that occur at least 4 times and the count for each of those values.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't exact enough. Please take a look for the update of the example.

Comment: What I would do is cache the taxonomy on the client and create a facet for PRODUCT, getting the count for TV, Computer etc. and then on the client side generate the list (form the cached taxonomy). This since you are not interested in the count on the second level. If you are I would suggest that you go with Karls suggestion and index the taxonomy and parse it in the client for every request.